# Validating inclusion for Enumerated Types

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a Rails 7 app, I have defined an `enum` as defined [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#enumerated-types).
On several tutorials, I see validating the `status` with code like the one below

```
  validates :status, inclusion: { in: statuses.keys }
```

I'm wondering if the validation is required since when a value not in `statuses` is passed, Rails raises an `ArgumentError, "'#{value}' is not a valid #{name}"` (even when the validation is defined).

Is there an advantage to adding the validation?

Comment: Please see the answer, now (in rails 7.1+) it is possible to validate enum

Comment: Yes. A failed validation and an exception are two completely different things. Validations just ensure that the user input complies to the rules of your business logic while exceptions are a language level construct for handling unforseen errors in the program. Invalid user input is not exceptional and should thus not be treated that way.

Comment: @max, the difference is clear. However, in Rails 7.0, the validation doesn't seem to be never checked since `ArgumentError` is raised before validating the record. That was the motivation of the question.

Answer (score 2):

**Rails 7.1+**

After [pull request](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/49100) it is possible to validate enum such way

```rb
class Conversation < ApplicationRecord
  enum :status, %i[active archived], validate: true
end

conversation = Conversation.new

conversation.status = :unknown
conversation.valid? # => false

conversation.status = nil
conversation.valid? # => false

conversation.status = :active
conversation.valid? # => true
```

**Before rails 7.1**

Rails [automatically validate](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/bb52c41dbfdf8d57b58f82319506446b70bca1b1/activerecord/lib/active_record/enum.rb#L166-L170) this value

```rb
def assert_valid_value(value)
  unless value.blank? || mapping.has_key?(value) || mapping.has_value?(value)
    raise ArgumentError, "'#{value}' is not a valid #{name}"
  end
end
```

What you can is override this method with empty body

```rb
# config/initializers/enum_prevent_argument_error.rb
module ActiveRecord
  module Enum
    class EnumType < Type::Value
      def assert_valid_value(_)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

After that validation will work. But you should double check that all enums have this validation. If there is no validation and no check constraint, invalid values will be saved as is in the database and will be as `nil` attriubute in the AR model